# Аргументы метода LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq

Не понимаю, почему так. Есть вызов асинхронного метода

```
tasks = request.Sets
                .Select(x => _service.MethodAsync(...))
                .ToArray();
```

Также приведу объявление вызываемой функции:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyDictionary<long, TValue>> MethodAsync(...)
```

Как видно, она возвращает

```
Task<IReadOnlyDictionary<long, TValue>>
```

при этом, далее есть блок, в котором мы дожидаемся тред и здесь есть непонятная для меня вещь:

```
cache = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
                    .Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, IReadOnlyDictionary<long, TValue>>(request.Sets[i].Id, x))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Rider подсказывает, что тип `x` -- `IReadOnlyDictionary<long, TValue>>`, а тип `i` -- `int`. Таким образом, мне непонятно, почему `Select` ожидает делегата с двумя аргументами, вместо делегата с одним аргументом типа `IReadOnlyDictionary<long, TValue>>`?

Comment: Напишите `x` вместо `(x, i)` - тоже прекрасно будет работать (правда, у вас `i` используется, но это уже детали). Две перегрузки метода [Enumerable.Select](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2). А вопрос в чём?

Comment: Вы вызываете перегруженную функцию Select, второй аргумент - индекс элемента в последовательности

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо